# Can I transfer the elastic IP one region to another region in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-ip

I have elastic IP in North Virginia region, I want transfer the same elastic IP to another region is it possible ?

Comment: I don't know the specifics of AWS, but given my knowledge of routing in general I'd say that's highly unlikely to be possible. Supporting that would introduce a significant risk of shared fate which defeats the reliability gains from having independent regions. And as far as I know AWS doesn't have a private backbone, which makes it even worse.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From the [Elastic IP Addresses section in the EC2 documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html):

> An Elastic IP address is for use in a specific region only.

Answer (score 1):

No One Elastic Ip can be used in one region only.
[image]